# Oracle 11g 64-bit client connecting to 8i

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, 32bit-64bit, oracle8i

So here's the problem. I have to connect to both Oracle 8i and 11g databases. I have a 64-bit OS. Can I use the same 11g 64-bit client to connect to 8i? If this doesn't work, is there any other client that allows me to connect to 8i on my 64-bit OS? (on a previous 32-bit OS it was piece of cake to have the both clients installed). Thank you!

Comment: Which client? [That isn't supported for JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/getsta.htm#i1008205), but not sure if that's what you mean...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 10.2.0 client is the latest client to support both 11g and 8.1.7.  It shouldn't matter if it's 32 or 64 bit.

For more information look at the Client / Server / Interoperability Support Matrix For Different Oracle Versions (Doc ID 207303.1) on support.oracle.com.  Unfortunately the document cannot be posted here, it can only be viewed with a valid support license.  A valid support contract will also be needed to download 10g software since it's not on the [public download page anymore](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html).  That bottom of that page mentions using Oracle Support Document 1071023.1 to request the software.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. It did work with the Oracle 9 client, I manage to connect to both databases. So you can connect to 8i from a 64-bit system, Windows 8.1.